# Ellipse in 3D space tilted wrt z-axis

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

This seems to be very hard to find.  I am looking for the parametric equation of an ellipse that is parallel to the x-y plane and tilted wrt the z-axis.

In 2D the parametric equations are x = a*cos(u) and y = b*sin(u), where 'u' is the parameter and 'a' and 'b' are the semi-major and semi-minor axes respectively.

In 3D x, y, and z will be functions of  the parameters 'u' and 'v', and 'a' and 'b' are as above.  What will the parametric equations be?

Comment: How can an ellipse be parallel to the $x,y$ plane (implying that it is in a plane perpendicular to the $z$ axis) and simultaneously be "tilted" with respect to the $z$ axis?

Comment: If you know the center $C$ of the ellipse, and its major semi-axis and minor semi-axis as vectors then the parametric equation is $P(t) = C + V_{major} \cos \theta + V_{minor} \sin \theta $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you take an ellipse that is parallel to the $xy$-plane and tilt the ellipse along one of its semi-axes.

Notice that if you look at the ellipse from above (i.e. project it down to the $xy$-plane), the ellipse will look like an ellipse (possibly a circle).

By looking at the ellipse from the front ($xz$-plane) or the side ($yz$-plane) (depending on which semi-axis you tilted with respect to), the ellipse will still look like an ellipse.

However, when looking at from the other perspective, the ellipse will look just like a straight diagonal line.

Thus, when you create your parametrization for the entire ellipse, when you look at the ways of pairing the parametrizations of $x, y, z$, two of the pairs should be the parametrization of an ellipse and one of the pairs should be the parametrization of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Using matrices, you can rotate the ellipse if you think of the parametric equations as a vector, $\vec{r}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} {a}\cos{t} \\ {b}\sin{t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. For example, to rotate the ellipse by an angle $\theta$ about the x-axis, you compute the following:  $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ 0 & \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} {a}\cos{t} \\ {b}\sin{t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations for more info.